# EDITED: Converting monthly asset returns to monthly portfolio returns: tidyquant, PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r

I have some data on monthly asset returns and I want to combine these assets into a portfolio. For each month I want to calculate the returns for all assets held in that month.

I am obtaining two different results from calculating the returns.

I run the following code:

Method 1:

```
mean(data[data$date == "2007-06-29",]$monthly.returns)

Output1
    [1] 0.1061636
```

Method 2:

```
data %>%
  tq_portfolio(assets_col  = ID, 
               returns_col = monthly.returns,
               col_rename  = "returns",
               rebalance_on = "months") %>%
  filter(date == "2007-06-29")


Output2
    # A tibble: 1 x 2
      date       returns
      <date>       <dbl>
    1 2007-06-29  0.0212
```

Method 3:

```
data %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(ave_month_ret = mean(monthly.returns)) %>%
  filter(date == "2007-06-29")

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  date       ave_month_ret
  <date>             <dbl>
1 2007-06-29         0.106
```

Which is consistent with method 1. I just do not know what calculation method 2 is using...

The returns are much smaller… and I am using the same data/code.

EDIT
NEW Data:

```
   data <- structure(list(ID = c("94106L10", "94106L10", "94106L10", "94106L10", 
"94106L10", "94106L10", "94106L10", "94106L10", "94106L10", "94106L10", 
"94106L10", "94106L10", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "50540R40", "50540R40", "50540R40", "50540R40", 
"50540R40", "50540R40", "50540R40", "50540R40", "50540R40", "50540R40", 
"50540R40", "50540R40", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", 
"48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", 
"48116510", "48116510", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", 
"58283910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", 
"58283910", "58283910", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", 
"48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", 
"48116510", "48116510", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", 
"48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", "48116510", 
"48116510", "48116510", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "58943310", "58943310", "58943310", "58943310", 
"58943310", "58943310", "58943310", "58943310", "58943310", "58943310", 
"58943310", "58943310", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", 
"58283910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", "58283910", 
"58283910", "58283910", "90781810", "90781810", "90781810", "90781810", 
"90781810", "90781810", "90781810", "90781810", "90781810", "90781810", 
"90781810", "90781810", "22207020", "22207020", "22207020", "22207020", 
"22207020", "22207020", "22207020", "22207020", "22207020", "22207020", 
"22207020", "22207020", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "11012210", 
"11012210", "11012210", "11012210", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", 
"74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "74144T10", "12526910", "12526910", 
"12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910", "12526910"), 
    date = structure(c(13693, 13725, 13756, 13784, 13817, 13847, 
    13878, 13909, 13938, 13969, 13999, 14029, 13693, 13725, 13756, 
    13784, 13817, 13847, 13878, 13909, 13938, 13969, 13999, 14029, 
    14425, 14456, 14487, 14517, 14547, 14578, 14609, 14638, 14666, 
    14699, 14729, 14757, 14425, 14456, 14487, 14517, 14547, 14578, 
    14609, 14638, 14666, 14699, 14729, 14757, 14425, 14456, 14487, 
    14517, 14547, 14578, 14609, 14638, 14666, 14699, 14729, 14757, 
    14790, 14820, 14852, 14882, 14911, 14943, 14974, 15005, 15033, 
    15064, 15093, 15121, 14790, 14820, 14852, 14882, 14911, 14943, 
    14974, 15005, 15033, 15064, 15093, 15121, 15155, 15184, 15217, 
    15247, 15278, 15308, 15338, 15370, 15399, 15429, 15460, 15490, 
    15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 
    15792, 15825, 15855, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 15674, 
    15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15855, 15884, 15917, 15947, 
    15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 16220, 
    15884, 15917, 15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 
    16160, 16190, 16220, 15884, 15917, 15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 
    16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 16220, 15884, 15917, 15947, 
    15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 16220, 
    15884, 15917, 15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 
    16160, 16190, 16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 
    16435, 16465, 16493, 16525, 16555, 16584, 16251, 16282, 16311, 
    16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 16465, 16493, 16525, 16555, 16584, 
    16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 16465, 16493, 
    16525, 16555, 16584, 16616, 16647, 16678, 16708, 16738, 16769, 
    16800, 16829, 16860, 16891, 16920, 16948, 16616, 16647, 16678, 
    16708, 16738, 16769, 16800, 16829, 16860, 16891, 16920, 16948, 
    16616, 16647, 16678, 16708, 16738, 16769, 16800, 16829, 16860, 
    16891, 16920, 16948, 16982, 17011, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 
    17165, 17197, 17225, 17256, 17284, 17316, 16982, 17011, 17044, 
    17074, 17105, 17135, 17165, 17197, 17225, 17256, 17284, 17316, 
    16982, 17011, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 17165, 17197, 17225, 
    17256, 17284, 17316, 17347, 17378, 17409, 17438, 17470, 17500, 
    17529, 17562, 17590, 17619, 17651, 17681, 17347, 17378, 17409, 
    17438, 17470, 17500, 17529, 17562, 17590, 17619, 17651, 17681, 
    17347, 17378, 17409, 17438, 17470, 17500, 17529, 17562, 17590, 
    17619, 17651, 17681, 17711, 17743, 17774, 17802, 17835, 17865, 
    17896, 17711, 17743, 17774, 17802, 17835, 17865, 17896, 17711, 
    17743, 17774, 17802, 17835, 17865, 17896), class = "Date"), 
    monthly.returns = c(-0.0227727694760084, -0.0261203707475507, 
    -0.00946622723920743, 0.00185833588861728, -0.0357711242389441, 
    -0.0568837518423548, -0.0480769679647677, -0.00795832066438062, 
    0.0129590245485958, 0.0222357447920023, 0.0756852502053702, 
    0.0506925736400397, 0.23509996528303, -0.0402404386704445, 
    0.101774570901307, 0.198642056960844, 0.157950168427595, 
    0.0350398381978172, 0.209716349721439, -0.0284390089301215, 
    0.141681487726935, -0.151212310022894, 0.29029138587484, 
    0.0239341587231359, 0.0962160534970569, -0.00885084033069661, 
    0.0386962104427435, -0.0586044406595664, 0.0485540729007834, 
    0.0590796883565639, 0.025767506537949, -0.0499732502241718, 
    0.031082969506351, 0.0327377111690756, 0.0377757316726486, 
    -0.0376734007378084, -0.006674674348077, 0.120950351259758, 
    -0.0301862529447343, 0.00883005590763375, 0.0663019415473178, 
    0.00410426359159222, 0.0882893862227756, -0.0681690341430085, 
    0.0215638798439521, 0.084434853224457, 0.0467527676505903, 
    -0.139381305703097, -0.0722062821678602, 0.0647424209775214, 
    0.0344565636759657, 0.0559637458961404, -0.0345587758427702, 
    0.0253453526768961, 0.0634957606629634, 0.0229125562791819, 
    0.144087843694531, -0.14175449794253, -0.0823645767832291, 
    -0.180231889100862, 0.0843478493068521, -0.000801942956512258, 
    0.0465489503956982, 0.0394938914746412, -0.00774625551801411, 
    -0.0617100323774203, 0.0491283590476501, -0.0490936276258981, 
    0.0250198233967893, 0.0240217300295384, 0.0631857758990213, 
    0.0131672215965088, -0.113795183581069, 0.0865059744398955, 
    -0.0920588569116774, 0.143297501255742, 0.103964885125911, 
    0.0553645982983011, 0.106463207432413, 0.0213820457676193, 
    0.0160801762353151, -0.00836078172471943, -0.032670855597221, 
    -0.0281712275998599, 0.00717743792807513, -0.058667565571353, 
    -0.0584506996376505, -0.106768869359527, 0.106133549220015, 
    0.0741861876916237, 0.00334747087781739, 0.015627732708084, 
    0.0648340247252268, 0.0602370983922462, -0.0334609689307233, 
    -0.0913412509075884, 0.140166564517708, -0.035101637811455, 
    0.0113580020857449, 0.0302734481107707, 0.0249604744929042, 
    -0.0032367307854908, 0.00691364497253999, 0.0966397419387792, 
    -0.00308081794455839, 0.0516926559765842, -0.0316549039620571, 
    0.0691034777411104, 0.212769987437646, 0.0104262875833523, 
    0.0574683301781924, 0.0735713800805162, -0.0767188743265328, 
    0.0430820031810046, -0.0507872502882032, 0.128027141356501, 
    -0.123663640809552, -0.0520838849698677, -0.0202763077657058, 
    0.0438046132087873, -0.0972842207128838, 0.0199876621698352, 
    -0.00767678925485249, 0.0390879891163065, 0.111873020808188, 
    -0.00334799342218495, 0.0341230597297544, -0.0974525662398461, 
    0.0418639713230742, 0.0545454545454545, 0.0410345011744, 
    -0.053494526086419, -0.0609372035423539, -0.032445670011178, 
    -0.0358465076686083, 0.1100983522136, 0.134831500498185, 
    -0.0217060049450167, 0.0344492102173604, -0.0598306719450883, 
    0.0760456102507803, -0.0338478645960549, -0.0358036685858628, 
    -0.00698739215521882, -0.0365886586715675, 0.0278688661280919, 
    -0.0677830757432401, 0.0255204010707701, 0.0761852263823679, 
    0.0394005332395586, 0.0411384240151262, -0.0636265299659813, 
    0.034803616044994, 0.0145373947492247, -0.00267153885585358, 
    -0.00730547295977324, -0.113969817301305, 0.142915419864933, 
    -0.0289270870253876, 0.107649500301504, 0.0226248837026684, 
    0.00825602378898527, 0.0720396911011352, -0.00935458607357742, 
    0.0868058270516758, 0.0388203307648247, -0.0593539579882222, 
    -0.0075865751284514, -0.0410312185542581, -0.0806513536324847, 
    0.0300659328873014, -0.0102625170677582, 0.0996498964853725, 
    0.0349007879783321, -0.00887468916153855, -0.0820200880058296, 
    0.0606061087150531, 0.0194971953205381, 0.061582905751375, 
    0.0137094839699294, 0.061358175546423, -0.0376746255364924, 
    0.0656429853952964, -0.136342049126051, -0.0350201652979498, 
    -0.0682120478762982, -0.0513866315399212, -0.0984523169816596, 
    0.0567477621851786, -0.115974716268977, 0.0883103383747428, 
    -0.0867730022490958, -0.0118150708749615, 0.0434962004402912, 
    0.000592702382994359, 0.010463943994673, 0.136967531843181, 
    0.0147791825167145, -0.000338703776833316, 0.021006296867851, 
    0.0107847636675746, 0.0587656260449405, -0.0119379915932356, 
    0.0136513249354131, 0.0327908992426151, -0.0799668251054702, 
    0.0429435864950873, -0.0320390287388762, 0.0470662594412536, 
    0.0168108776266995, 0.028633034080461, -0.0831586226286106, 
    0.0492885822313425, -0.0196125320473831, 0.00246970782849543, 
    -0.00603594311317535, -0.0777069869314776, -0.27044200854134, 
    -0.0829231558769659, -0.38356726967603, 0.150703278902144, 
    -0.106519202048837, -0.178501671446223, -0.209357609954451, 
    0.295887635933256, 0.243808018570374, 0.325451128908283, 
    -0.218309849065137, 0.0112461676208042, -0.0135257215734256, 
    -0.0939975354405369, -0.00454011185844061, 0.114020204363381, 
    0.0160728618201482, 0.0265631804589126, -0.0963803020769938, 
    -0.0037001213449307, 0.0314871750901062, 0.129931106735742, 
    -0.0120532383333837, -0.0317637700689766, -0.00771910559118838, 
    -0.0680669024627425, -0.0331107031769513, 0.088057593476, 
    0.00700871145261717, -0.0611950567135018, -0.00755351701865092, 
    -0.0259337056664409, 0.0629431114991126, 0.0249115417078927, 
    0.0244387875616459, 0.0208456520176783, 0.0495087594370764, 
    -0.0264316930765137, -0.0197963653645624, -0.127716926139201, 
    0.224917334203661, 0.0648065227409875, 0.0363482274846763, 
    0.0228385243605778, 0.0303029934300199, -0.0936532411759149, 
    -0.0785653037414443, -0.0515986625257318, -0.0312457001665778, 
    -0.0162682343494345, -0.0437158595844728, -0.0374435768987895, 
    0.157006640946117, 0.016203140928911, -0.103906450609303, 
    0.0559014903112138, -0.0429714590357441, 0.0402053969540854, 
    -0.0156580705305179, 0.0904830409618358, -0.0170799234353476, 
    -0.0463004192232698, -0.0712354247129779, -0.0536641612267443, 
    -0.0358432583322087, -0.0184490812764968, -0.00423972643726345, 
    0.245955181042198, 0.0146941667852203, -0.00404131794961526, 
    0.00710096082901068, -0.0205934653685186, -0.0546323053674277, 
    0.0227273114616595, 0.101329514337245, -0.00155212816488148, 
    0.0924950254753545, 0.0600790996325375, -0.00447431824166233, 
    -0.0243445692883895, 0.0320920742862265, -0.00595096211080237, 
    0.0936166583081903, -0.0172865333194544, 0.0916843972478469, 
    -0.19042967312998, -0.00301563554226025, -0.0683606183409371, 
    0.118831166820551, 0.154381887294401, -0.0140773649014047, 
    -0.0147884195054189, -0.0527950555836166, -0.0519125079342569, 
    -0.216714705833528, 0.0374668020538464, 0.114674602361112, 
    0.0198259110909933, 0.0745614138219373, 0.0248207386886548, 
    0.107857873826567, 0.0195297529342309, 0.0638520626013142, 
    0.00241874298221156, -0.0351206456799478, 0.0541817023986408, 
    0.0744157550818212, 0.0756073728272992, 0.0616190791111271, 
    0.0306382848861362, 0.0252684164041697, -0.185889184522457, 
    0.0577759817184391, -0.0276842418178466, -0.0576345966621118, 
    0.0257559271899821, -0.0267887335602566, -0.057899724909925, 
    -0.111650507486109, 0.0244355376717398, -0.0708534709368143, 
    0.0944047784043569, 0.000450374828359967, 0.169518300414036, 
    0.0479306607738461, -0.117744305824932, -0.121590678763565, 
    0.0312870286274094)), row.names = c(NA, -345L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I also apply `sum(is.na(x))` which gives me `0`, however I get the following `warning Warning message:
In PerformanceAnalytics::Return.portfolio(., weights = weights,  :
  NA's detected: filling NA's with zeros`